# How to implement Lightning Network in to a cryptocurrency exchange

Tags: exchanges, multi-signature, lightning-network

A highly potent use-case for the lightning network are the millions of transactions that occur on a daily basis. There's still a good chance of data breach and hacks due to centralization. The possibility of centralized exchanges scamming people, and many more...

This question aims at a detailed step-wise implementation of the Lightning Network in a Binance like cryptocurrency exchange.